# Determine whether the following statement is true or not.

Tags: sequences-and-series

i) If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(bn){(x+1)^n}}$ converges at x=3 then it converges at x=4

I choosed $an=1/2^n$ and i applied ratio test for all of the series and i found the convergence of interval [-3,1] and radius of convergence 2 but i am comfused. Please write any counter-example if there is. I would be appreciative for any answer.

Answer (score 2):

$a_n=\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n2^{n}}$ is  a counter-example for i); take $a_n=0$ for all $n$ for ii). I will leave iii) to you.

Comment: Sir so 2nd statement (ii) is false when we take an=0 ?

Comment: @Bl3stal Yes it is false.

Comment: Then we can say the 3rd statement is false if we take again an=0. So an=0 is a counter example for iii right?